# Authentication error on execution of post-commit hook in SVN

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I've got a SVN post-commit hook that updates a working copy when a commit is made to the repository. The post-commit hook executes the following command:

```
/usr/bin/svn update /path/to/working/copy
```

It was working fine until I enabled the Apache mod_dav `Require valid-user` directive. Authentication is fine when using the tortoisesvn client for windows as it asks for your user name and password and saves the details. But as this is a non-interactive process the username and password is not supplied and the update fails.

Apache runs as user and group `nobody` and `nogroup` this is also the user and group that owns the repositories and the working copies.

The `nobody` user does not have a password as it cannot login in. It's just used to run Apache etc. I tried adding `nobody` to the `dav_svn.passwd` file using the following command:

```
htpasswd dav_svn.passwd nobody
```

I get the following error when trying to run the post-commit script directly at the command line:

```
Authentication realm:
```

---

Update:

Adding the following to the dav_svn.conf:

```
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Satisfy any
```

Fixes the issue but then causes another issue in that the tortoisesvn client no longer requires authentication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Apache is asking your `svn update` process for a password.  Which is kind of annoying for a non-interactive process. ;-)

I think you might want to re-checkout your working copy using a direct file system path instead of going through Apache.

Answer (score 1):

This may help as it will allow the server to access itself:

```
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Require valid-user
Satisfy any
```

Comment: It turned out adding this indeed fixes the issue of the post-commit scripts not working but tortoisesvn no longer or requires that Windows users supply a username and password. So I can only guess that the web dav URL's used to specify location of repository resolve to 127.0.0.1.